# зацикливание триггера update

Tags: sql, sql-server, update, триггер

есть два триггера. один обновляет из центральной бд в периферийные бд. а другой наоборот, если периферийная бд обновляется, то обновить центральную. получается выдается ошибка "Превышен максимальный уровень вложенности хранимой процедуры, функции, триггера или представления (ограничение 32)." как сделать если первый триггер сработал (из центральной или и периферийной), то второй не будет работать? подскажите пожалуйста.

```
USE V_test
go
declare @basename1 nvarchar(100), @basename2 nvarchar(100), --@triggername nvarchar(50), 
@sql nvarchar(MAX)
select @basename1 = '[V_test]'
select @basename2 = '[B_test]'
--select @triggername = 'B_test_update_V_test'
select @sql = '
ALTER TRIGGER V_test_update_B_test
ON '+@basename1+'.[dbo].[fpTable] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS '+
'
IF OBJECT_ID (N'''+@basename1+'.[dbo].[fpTable]'', N''U'') IS  NULL return '+
'
UPDATE tab2 
SET
tab2.minimu=tab1.minimu
FROM '+@basename1+'.[dbo].[fpTable] tab1,  '+@basename2+'.[dbo].[fpTable]  tab2
WHERE tab1.stor = tab2.stor
AND tab2.prod = tab1.prod 
AND tab2.prod = ''7183'' AND tab1.stor = ''ВЗ'''
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: первое что приходит в голову - отключать триггер обновляемой БД на время изменений и снова включать по окончании

Comment: Вам надо менять логику. Допустим, в таблицы добавить поле `from` куда передавать флаги, кто меняет и эти же флаги отслеживать в триггере(если апдейт триггера, то не обновлять). Либо рядом табличку временную создать, куда класть id записи и оба триггера натравить на нее. Если тригер сработал, а втабоице по id запись есть, то основную таблицу не обновлять, а во временной запись удалить. Ну как то так...

Comment: Ваша логика хромает аж на обе ноги. По факту вы хотите в триггере определять, что является источником изменения - запрос в клиентском коде или в другом триггере, и в зависимости от этого либо выполнять обновление, либо нет. Однако вы используете триггер AFTER UPDATE, и уже на момент начала работы триггера, до выполнения желаемого определения, обновление произведено. То есть вам надо не просто определить источник, но и откатывать уже сделанные изменения. В то же время BEFORE триггеры тоже нелогичны, и по аналогичной причине. Следовательно, надо использовать INSTEAD OF триггеры. Это первое.

Comment: И второе. Триггеры в SQL Server, если я правильно помню, не принимают родительского контекста исполнения. Соответственно простейшая схема передачи признака в какой-либо сессионной переменной вряд ли сработает. Если это так, то признак придётся передавать в одном из полей, внося туда данные, не проходящие программного логического контроля, но проходящие контроль типа. Например, это может быть добавление первым символом CHAR(0) в поле строкового типа, или отрицательное значение в заведомо положительном числовом поле. И при обнаружении такого "флага" триггер убирает его, и не каскадит.

Answer (score 0):

получилось сделать так. может криво, но работает

```
USE MHH1_test
GO
ALTER TRIGGER ZHILMHH1_test_update_BC_test
ON MHH1_test.[dbo].[TAB1] 
AFTER UPDATE  
AS
BEGIN
    -- Проверяем, есть ли изменения в таб1
    DECLARE @cc int, @cc1 varchar(50)--int
    
    set @cc= 0
    BEGIN     
        PRINT @cc
        
        INSERT INTO  BC_test.dbo.ImportTriggerUpdate (ID, keyUpd, cdb, pdb, tex, del)
        SELECT (select count(ID)+1 from BC_test.dbo.ImportTriggerUpdate),storage+product, 1, 0, 'MHH1_test_update_BC_test', 1 
        FROM INSERTED

        set @cc=(SELECT count(ttt.keyUpd)
        FROM BC_test.dbo.ImportTriggerUpdate ttt, BC_test.[dbo].[TAB1]  tab1
        WHERE ttt.keyUpd = tab1.storage + tab1.product  AND tab1.storage = 'Зал1')  
        
        set @cc1=(SELECT TOP 1 (ttt.keyUpd)
        FROM BC_test.dbo.ImportTriggerUpdate ttt, BC_test.[dbo].[TAB1]  tab1
        WHERE ttt.keyUpd = tab1.storage + tab1.product  AND tab1.storage = 'Зал1' GROUP BY ttt.keyUpd)
        
        

        IF @cc>1
            BEGIN
        -- Выводим сообщение или выполняем другие действия по необходимости
                PRINT @cc1+'!'--'Условие выполнено. Работа триггера прекращена.';
                --RETURN; -- Прекращаем работу триггера
            END
        
        -- Обняем таб2
        IF @cc=1
            BEGIN
            --PRINT 'обновление периф.';
            UPDATE tab2
            SET   
            tab2.novr=tab1.novr,
            tab2.decsr=tab1.decsr
            FROM BC_test.[dbo].[TAB1] tab2,  MHH1_test.[dbo].[TAB1]  tab1
            WHERE tab1.storage = tab2.storage
            AND tab2.product = tab1.product
            AND (tab1.storage + tab1.product) = @cc1
                
            
            --DELETE FROM BC_test.dbo.ImportTriggerUpdate
            --WHERE keyUpd=@cc1 
            --очистить врем таблицу
            TRUNCATE TABLE BC_test.dbo.ImportTriggerUpdate
            
        END
    END
    
END;
```